# Unable to start Selenium server due to error "UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY"

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

***I have uninstalled/reinstalled nodejs, protractor, selenium, webdriver-manager but error continues.*

  *- What else should I uninstall or update?

  - Can someone please provide next steps or some direction to correct issue?

  - where do i get the local certificate?***

my commands:
1. webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl --proxy http://password@proxy.path.com:8080
2. webdriver-managerstart ---(error details below)

Current global installed versions:
protractor Version 5.4.3
webdriver-manager 12.1.7
selenium standalone version available: 3.141.59
chromedriver version available: 80.0.3987.106
geckodriver version available: v0.26.0

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate  
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)  
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)  
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)  
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12) {  
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'  
}  
[13:56:46] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.26.0.exe -jar  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444  
[13:56:46] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 2884    
13:56:46.834 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358  
13:56:46.957 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444  
2020-03-17 13:56:47.035:INFO::main: Logging initialized @513ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog  
13:56:47.373 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet  
13:56:48.375 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the `webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl` from your local project node modules, probably your command is running globally, Try the below options , either one should work

1. Run `./node_modules/webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl --proxy` with proxy
2. Run `./node_modules/webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl` without proxy

Comment: I mean i see scripts are running from this path "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules".
suggestion is to delete the webdriver-manager folder from here "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\webdriver-manager\"
and do 'npm i webdriver-manager -g' then you should see the webdriver-manager folder comes back again,

Once again try running like the below
<navigate to webdriver-manager executable> webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl

then you can run 'webdriver-manager start'

Answer (score 0):

"Run ./node_modules/webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl --proxy with proxy"

I ran suggestion above but get this error message with business proxy:

I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
**E/downloader - Expected response code 200, received: 403**
I/update - selenium standalone: file exists .AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar up to date
(node:72544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: response status code is not 200